# JMS DIExtraBundle / Annotations beyond Symfony Applications

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, annotations, php-di

I am currently developing a symfony application in which I want to have loose coupling of the business logic and the framework. I don't want to depend on the whole symfony framework and may be able exchange the framework later (and run my business logic outside of a bundle).

The Symfony DI Container is an independent component, which may be used without the whole symfony framework. So I basically can handle my dependencies with this component (in a yml file, via PHP, etc.).

Assume, I want to configure the dependencies with annotations using the [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle). Is there any possibility to use this bundle outside of an symfony application? If not, what may be the best option, to handle my dependencies? I would like to use annotations :)

- Configure the Container with PHP, Yaml or anything else and work without annotations
- Use another DI Container in combination with the Symfony one, which offers annotations (e.g. [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/))
- Do not build the applicatoin independently from symfony and don't ever exchange the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of PHP-DI here. Is there a reason why you want to keep Symfony's container?

You said you would be open to use PHP-DI with Symfony's container, so FYI there's [an integration possible with the documentation available here](http://php-di.org/doc/frameworks/symfony2.html). However I don't think it will suit you because it's an integration with the whole Symfony framework. If you want to know how it works, check out the [GitHub project](https://github.com/mnapoli/PHP-DI-Symfony2).

Now another solution, which might be better, would be to use both Symfony's container and PHP-DI. You can use [Acclimate](https://github.com/jeremeamia/acclimate-container) for that. Here is a quick example (not tested):

```
$sfContainer = /* ... */;
$phpdiContainer = /* ... */;

// Adapt Symfony's container. PHP-DI doesn't need this because it is compliant with
// Container Interop https://github.com/container-interop/container-interop
$acclimator = new ContainerAcclimator;
$sfContainer = $acclimator->acclimate($sfContainer);

$container = new CompositeContainer([$sfContainer, $phpdiContainer]);
```

Here, the composite container (`$container`) will first look for services in Symfony's container, then in PHP-DI's container.

Now the trick is that each container don't know about the other one. So if you use PHP-DI's annotations, you can't inject Symfony's services. But PHP-DI is awesome (hell yeah :p) so you can make it aware of the parent container (which is the composite container) using `ContainerBuilder::wrapContainer()`:

```
$container = new CompositeContainer();

// Add Symfony's container
$container->addContainer($acclimate->adaptContainer($symfonyContainer));

// Configure PHP-DI container
$builder = new ContainerBuilder();
$builder->wrapContainer($container);

// Add PHP-DI container
$phpdiContainer = $builder->build();
$container->addContainer($acclimate->adaptContainer($phpdiContainer));

// Good to go!
$foo = $container->get('foo');
```

This is taken from [PHP-DI's documentation](http://php-di.org/doc/container-configuration.html).

Now all is good in the world. The only problem left is that Symfony doesn't know PHP-DI's services, but Symfony's container don't have an equivalent feature, so there's no way around that (that's too bad). In my experience, I don't find it a big problem.

But all in all, I would advise you to use only PHP-DI and everything will be much simpler.